# Network problem with Apple music when using "Hey Siri"

Tags: iphone, itunes, siri, apple-music

I often use the "Hey Siri" function to switch between playlists or different artists in my itunes library (mostly while driving). After some recent update sometime within the last year, there is always a message saying "there was a network problem getting Apple Music"

The music always eventually plays, but there is just the error about the network issue being presented by Siri prior to the music starting.  It should be noted that I only ever play music & playlists that are on my iPhone, and that I never use cloud based or online services to play my music files.

It should be noted that this problem doesn't occur when I am at home and my phone is connected to my home wifi network. Also, 'Show Apple Music' is disabled in the music settings on the phone.

Running iOS 16.6.1 on iPhone12 pro

Answer (score 0):

I eventually tried some workarounds that I found people discussing on [other Apple support forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254686140?sortBy=best), which included **turning on mobile data for the Music app** in the Settings App. Doing this solved the problem.

That being said, I am not sure users need to have their phones tethering internet for Siri to understand the command to play locally stored music, but at least it works to remedy said issue.